# Ionic 4 - How to connect app to existing SQL Server via Web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

*Many similar questions have been asked, but none for this version of the Ionic framework and none have received answers that can actually help me.*

**BACKGROUND:**

I have made an app and need to fetch data from an existing SQL Server. From research the only way this can be done is to use a Web API as a middleware seeing as Ionic cannot directly connect to SQL Server.

Please refer to this tutorial as this is what I have been following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Js_8ijftKC0&index=21&list=PLaU76WfrROI6LO_YqTDd8ADul3xQoao5L&t=0s

**WHERE I AM AT SO FAR:**

- I have completed the Ionic side of the tutorial, adding the Service and all the CRUD operations etc.
- I have created a Web API in ASP.NET Web MVC in Visual Studio.
- The API is connected to my SQL database and enables CRUD operations.

**PROBLEM:**

After following this tutorial multiple times, not missing a hint. None of the CRUD methods in Ionic return anything. Nothing is updated or retrieved from the database on request.

- What is the tutorial missing? Is it even accurate?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

**sql.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestMethod, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SqlService {
  url:string="http://localhost:50287/api/APIDemo/"
  constructor(private http: Http) { }


getAll(){
  return this.http.get(this.url).pipe(map(res=>res.json()));
}

Create(name) {
  var body={"name":name};
  var header=new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
  var option=new RequestOptions({method:RequestMethod.Post,headers:header})
  return this.http.post(this.url + "Posttest",body,option).pipe(map(res=>res.json()))
}

Update(id, name) {
  var body={"id":id,"name":name};
  var header=new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
  var option=new RequestOptions({method:RequestMethod.Post,headers:header})
  return this.http.post(this.url,body,option).pipe(map(res=>res.json()))
}

Read(id) {
  return this.http.get(this.url+id).pipe(map(res=>res.json()))
}

Delete(id) {
  return this.http.delete(this.url+id).pipe(map(res=>res.json()))
}

}
```

**sql.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SqlService } from '../../services/sql.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sql',
  templateUrl: './sql.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sql.page.scss'],
})
export class SqlPage implements OnInit {
  items=[];
  id: string;
  name: string;

  constructor(public sql: SqlService) { 
    this.getAll()
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getAll() {
    this.items=[];
    this.sql.getAll().subscribe(data=>{
      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        this.items.push(data[i]);
      }
    })

  }

  Add() {
    if(this.id==null){
    this.sql.Create(this.name).subscribe(data=>{
      this.name="";
      this.getAll();
    })
  }else {
    this.sql.Update(this.id, this.name).subscribe(data=>{
      this.id=null
      this.name=""
      this.getAll()
    })
  }        
}

  Edit(item) {
    this.id = item.id
    this.name = item.name
  }

  Delete(item) {
    this.sql.Delete(item.id).subscribe(data=>{
      this.getAll()
    })

  }

}
```

**sql.page.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>sql</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Name</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="id" hidden></ion-input>
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-button (click)="Add()">Add</ion-button>

  <ion-list>
  <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let items of items">
    {{ item.name }}
  <ion-button (click)="Edit(item)">Edit</ion-button>
  <ion-button (click)="Delete(item)">Delete</ion-button>


  </li>
  </ul>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { EmailComposer } from '@ionic-native/email-composer/ngx';
import { EmailPageModule } from './pages/email/email.module';
import { MapsPageModule } from './pages/maps/maps.module';
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number/ngx';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'
import { SqlService } from './services/sql.service'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule, EmailPageModule, MapsPageModule, HttpModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    EmailComposer,
    CallNumber,
    SqlService,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

*DemoAPI (C#)*

WebApiConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace DemoAPI
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "http://localhost:8100", headers: "*", methods: "*"));

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

APIDemoController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using DemoAPI.Models;

namespace DemoAPI.Controllers
{
    public class APIDemoController : ApiController
    {
        private demoEntities db = new demoEntities();

        // GET: api/APIDemo
        public IQueryable<test> Gettests()
        {
            return db.tests;
        }

        // GET: api/APIDemo/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(test))]
        public IHttpActionResult Gettest(int id)
        {
            test test = db.tests.Find(id);
            if (test == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(test);
        }

        // PUT: api/APIDemo/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public IHttpActionResult Puttest(int id, test test)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != test.id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(test).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!testExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        // POST: api/APIDemo
        [HttpPost]
        [ResponseType(typeof(test))]
        public HttpResponseMessage Posttest(test test)
        {

            if (test.id == 0)
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.tests.Add(test);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, test);
                    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultAPI", new { id = test.id }));
                    return response;
                }
                else
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Entry(test).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    try
                    {
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                    {
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
                    }
                    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, test);
                    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultAPI", new { id = test.id }));
                    return response;
                }
                else
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
            }

        }




        // DELETE: api/APIDemo/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(test))]
        public IHttpActionResult Deletetest(int id)
        {
            test test = db.tests.Find(id);
            if (test == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.tests.Remove(test);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(test);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool testExists(int id)
        {
            return db.tests.Count(e => e.id == id) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code? "i can not get this to actually work" what does this mean? what errors are you receiving?

Comment: There'd be a lot of code that would need showing. I was hoping the link I provided would cover it as I've copied it word for word - start to finish. When entering text in to the 'ion-input' and clicking the add button (as shown in tutorial) Nothing happens. It doesn't add to the database. It doesn't appear any of the CRUD methods actually work at all. I want to find out what is missing from the tutorial. I am not receiving any errors, just nothing happens.

Comment: If there's any more information you need please do tell me, I appreciate the concern.

Comment: you do not necessarily have to show all the code, you can either paste the code where you are api calls and subscribing to them? or create a demo

Comment: Are you sure the port 13157 or other is same when you run api project from visual studio and specified in ionic app?

Comment: Apologies for delay in response, I've been ill. @Harry I've now edited this post with what I believe to be all the relevant code. If I've left out anything important please do let me know and I'll paste it in.

Comment: @DhavalThakkar It is the same yes, in my case port 50287

Comment: after ionic serve -> right click on page and select inspect element -> go to console -> you can see what error its throwing. or else you can share code in github repo and share ,link so i can check and get back to you about the error you are getting.

Comment: @DhavalThakkar I have provided more information and errors I am getting on the comment to the one answer. Do you know why I am getting these errors? Thanks

Comment: Update Route and Http Attributes for remaining methods like below.  This  might resolve your issue

1.
[Route("APIDemo")]
public class APIDemoController : ApiController

2.
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(test))]
public IHttpActionResult Gettest(int id)

3.
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public IHttpActionResult Puttest(int id, test test)
{

4.
[HttpDelete]
[ResponseType(typeof(test))]
public IHttpActionResult Deletetest(int id)

Comment: @DhavalThakkar After including all of this I am still getting 400 (Bad Request) Error when calling Posttest method. What could the problem be? My project files 
are here: https://github.com/JamesSlater/app

Comment: Can you please upload webapi project also in same repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try and simplify the original answer. Lets take a HTTP `GET` request.

In your service you have:

```
getAll(){
  return this.http.get(this.url).pipe(map(res=>res.json()));
}
```

In the web API you have a controller where you will define some actions. Your HTTP request gets mapped to the following route like so:

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"

Routing is how Web API matches a URI to an action
```

So in the WebAPI you would create an action like:

```
// GET: api/APIDemo/getall
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(test))]
public IHttpActionResult GetAll(int id)
{
    test test = db.tests.Find(id);
    if (test == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(test);
}
```

You a sample request can be like so:

```
localhost:8080/api/apidemo/getall?id=1
```

You also need to make a correct HTTP request, here we are retrieving a all tests,
The [HttpGet] attribute defines a GET.

You should read up on [Controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api#adding-a-controller) and [Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api#adding-a-controller).

**edit:**

okay so you need to create an object which matches what the method signature in the web API, so for your "Create" example.

```
Create(name) {
// use JSON.Stringigy to get an JSON string
  var body=JSON.stringify({id: 1, name:name});
  var header=new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
  var option=new RequestOptions({method:RequestMethod.Post,headers:header})
  return this.http.post(this.url + "Posttest",body,option).pipe(map(res=>res.json()))
}
```

Comment: Hi, after following your solution I am receiving the following errors in console when calling the create() method: 

POST http://localhost:50287/api/APIDemo/Puttest 400 (Bad Request) &       


`core.js:15723 ERROR 
Response {_body: "", status: 400, ok: false, statusText: "Bad Request", headers: Headers, …}
headers: Headers {_headers: Map(3), _normalizedNames: Map(3)}
ok: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
type: 2
url: "http://localhost:50287/api/APIDemo/Puttest"
_body: ""`

Comment: Create(name) {
  var body={"name":name};
  var header=new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
  var option=new RequestOptions({method:RequestMethod.Post,headers:header})
  return this.http.post(this.url,body,option).pipe(map(res=>res.json()))
} This method uses a "Post", and also you need to replace "http://localhost:50287/api/APIDemo/<YourAPIAction" here, this was an example

Comment: Yes that's identical to the create method I have except I've got the + "Puttest" after this.url (like you explained in the solution). I have also replaced that to 'locahost:50287/api/APIDemo/Puttest' - But I am still getting these errors: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) & the previous POST error.

Comment: Do you know why I am getting these errors and how I would fix them? I appreciate your help

Comment: You need to replace the puttest with the WebAPI controller action name

Comment: Thanks for the simplified solution. I have amended my code now, I am quite sure I have got it how it should be. BUT I am still getting the 400 (Bad Request) error. I am going to put my amended code in the original question so it's easier to see.

Comment: I have now updated the _Create_ method in **sql.service.ts** and _POST Controller Action_ in **APIDemoController.cs** - Is it not correct?

Comment: You need to pass in an object that matches "test" object, in your sql.services.ts

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please expand on this? As you can tell I'm new to this and I really want to get this working.

Comment: Can you show the structure of the test class, in your web api?

Comment: is that what you need?

Comment: Apologies, I didn't notice. After following your edited solution the error has now changed to a 404 (Not Found). Here is my github repo for this project: https://github.com/JamesSlater/app

Comment: In your web API change the origins value from 8100 to  config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "http://localhost:50287/api/APIDemo/" because in the sql.service.ts you are using 50287 ( is this correct port your api is listening on??

Comment: Yeah 50287 is what the mvc url opens up with. I had it as 50287 on web API before but I get an access error. In the video the guy uses 8100 for webapi config so I assumed I was doing it wrong. This is the error I get without even calling any methods:

Comment: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:50287/api/APIDemo/ from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Change 8100 to 50287

Comment: Yeah I have, that's the error I receive after doing so.

Comment: when you run the angular application, which port is it running on your machine?

Comment: Ionic angular application launches with the port 8100

Comment: Oh sorry - yes then ignore my comment - in the enable cors it does need to be 8100 and not 50287

Comment: No worries, making the enable cors port 8100 again I am back to receiving the 400 (Bad Request) error I mentioned earlier. What could the problem be?

Comment: I'm clicking a button calling 'Add' method which is a POST operation. Here's a screenshot of what I'm doing/seeing: https://imgur.com/a/5XvP6JP

Comment: can you console log the body object?

Comment: `{"Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of a non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult Puttest(Int32, DemoAPI.Models.test)' in 'DemoAPI.Controllers.APIDemoController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."}`

Comment: There you go - you need to pass in a value for id, it cannot be empty, now your request is getting through. Pass in the id and name and let me know

Comment: Sort of but not really as the id is supposed to auto-increment in the DB. I've managed to make it do this now but am having other problems. A record gets added to the DB but no 'name' gets passed through successfully and a few other issues. The C# guy at work thinks he knows what the issue is but has been off sick the past couple days. If I get it working, don't worry I won't forget to mark your solution as the answer. I've left this as ongoing as I might need your further assistance - I will let you know. Thank you.

Comment: okay great, you will need to create new questions for that. good luck!

Comment: I haven't been able to correct the issue. I've asked a new question, you might be able to help. Thanks for your help over the last couple weeks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55518131/error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined-ionic-4