# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined (Ionic 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

*No answers to similar questions have helped me*

**BACKGROUND:**

I have been configuring a SQL Server connection from my Ionic app. See my previous question for [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55283617/ionic-4-how-to-connect-app-to-existing-sql-server-via-web-api)

Ionic connects to ASP.NET MVC, and that connects to SQL Server.

I have managed to get records to be added to the SQL database, where the id property auto-increments but the name property is always NULL despite me passing a string for the property via ion-input.

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>
> ```
> at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (SqlPage.html:17)     
> at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:23936)     
> at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23311)     
> at callViewAction (core.js:23547)        
> at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:23510)         
> at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23307)       
> at callViewAction (core.js:23547)        
> at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23489)         
> at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23312)
> at callViewAction (core.js:23547)
> ```

Here are the relevant files, if there are other files you need to see let me know:

**sql.page.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>sql</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Name</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="id" hidden></ion-input>
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-button (click)="Add()">Add</ion-button>

  <ion-list>
  <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let items of items">
    {{ item.name }}
  <ion-button (click)="Edit(item)">Edit</ion-button>
  <ion-button (click)="Delete(item)">Delete</ion-button>


  </li>
  </ul>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**sql.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SqlService } from '../../services/sql.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sql',
  templateUrl: './sql.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sql.page.scss'],
})
export class SqlPage implements OnInit {
  items=[];
  id: string;
  name: string;

  constructor(public sql: SqlService) { 
    this.getAll()
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getAll() {
    this.items=[];
    this.sql.getAll().subscribe(data=>{
      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        this.items.push(data[i]);
      }
    })

  }

  Add() {
    if(this.id==null){
    this.sql.Create(this.name).subscribe(data=>{
      this.name=name;
      this.getAll();
    })
  }else {
    this.sql.Update(this.id, this.name).subscribe(data=>{
      //this.id=null
      this.name=name;
      this.getAll();
    })
  }        
}

  Edit(item) {
    this.id = item.id
    this.name = item.name
  }

  Delete(item) {
    this.sql.Delete(item.id).subscribe(data=>{
      this.getAll()
    })

  }

}
```

**sql.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestMethod, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SqlService {

  url:string="http://localhost:50287/api/APIDemo/"
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

getAll(){
  return this.http.get(this.url).pipe(map(res=>res.json()));
}

Create(name) {
  var body=JSON.stringify({name});
  var header=new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
  var option=new RequestOptions({method:RequestMethod.Post,headers:header})
  return this.http.post(this.url + "Posttest",body,option).pipe(map(res=>res.json()))
}

Update(id, name) {
  var body={"id":id,"name":name};
  var header=new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
  var option=new RequestOptions({method:RequestMethod.Post,headers:header})
  return this.http.post(this.url,body,option).pipe(map(res=>res.json()))
}

Read(id) {
  return this.http.get(this.url+id).pipe(map(res=>res.json()))
}

Delete(id) {
  return this.http.delete(this.url+id).pipe(map(res=>res.json()))
}

}
```

Why am I getting this error message, what have I done wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two issues here:

1 - change this in `*ngFor`

```
let items
```

change to

```
let item
```

2 -  In the class SqlPage

change

```
  items=[];
  id: string;
  name: string;
```

to

```
  items=[];
  id: string = "";
  name: string = "";
```

When you define a variable in JavaScript it has a default value of `undefined`

Comment: That got rid of all of the errors, thank you once again!

Comment: glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Start your VAR in contructor, like:

```
   constructor(public sql: SqlService) { 
        this.getAll();
        this.name = "";
      }
```

Comment: Put in your tag the propriety NAME="name"